# Change content of a p tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to replace the current content of a p with a new one? My current solution does not work. Response comes back so if I put one alert("Something") inside function(response) {} it works. The content does not get replaced, that is nothing happens!

```
             $(this).find(".caption").find("#yes").live('click', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'prob.php',
                    data: {action: 'yes'},
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (response) {
                            $(this).find(".caption").find("#change").html("<p>Come on!</p>");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

And this is my html:

```
                 <li>
                        <a class="thumb" name="leaf" href="<?php echo $images_dir.$_SESSION['current_img'].".jpg" ?>" title="Title #0">
                            <img src="<?php echo $images_dir.'thumbs/'.$_SESSION['current_img'].".jpg" ?>" alt='Title #0' />
                        </a>
                        <div class="caption" id="current">
                        <div class="image-title">
                            <p id="change">Image shows a nautillus shell:  
                                <input type="checkbox" id="yes">Yes
                                <input type="checkbox" id="no">No
                            </p>
                        </div>                                 
                    </li>
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the success not fire, does the wrong element get changed? Does something get added unexpectedly? Please say *exactly* what is not working so we know what it is you're encountering without needing to reverse engineer your code. Good luck!

Comment: `this` in your success handler refers to window object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need to traverse the DOM tree? Because both elements you need have a (hopefully) unique ID which means you can access them directly.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2NTr/) is a simplified js fiddle with your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#yes').on('click', function () {

        $('#change').text('Come on!');

    });
});
```

If this is not possible for you I have another advice because others already mentioned your problem with `$(this)` in the given context.
I'd like to recommend you to replace .live() with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of jQuery v1.7 and was removed in 1.9

**EDIT**

I also set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2NTr/2/) where #yes and #change have been changed to classes. In this fiddle you have 2 `<li>` tags and the "Come on!" text gets inserted in the right `<p class"change">`.

Comment: +1 on replacing live with on.  on is the standard going forward!

Comment: You might want to point out that id's won't work if there is more than one caption. The fact that he's using id="yes" and id="no" for options  suggests that there could eventually be others on the page, in which case, the behavior of getElementById for cases where there exists more than one id with the same value, is undefined, as per the spec.

Comment: there is more than one caption on the page.

Comment: if I replace live with on I get the following error:Browser Javascript error at position (19:17): Object doesn't support property or method 'on' 11:00:49 PM example-3.php?DBGSESSID=-1 (19:17)

Comment: Do you use a jQuery version below 1.7? Because .on() was introduced with v 1.7

Comment: See my edit, I made another fiddle. I hope I understood you right. If you want to change the text but leave the two inputs I can make another fiddle but probably tomorrow ^^

Answer (score 3):

Inside you ajax success `this` context will be ajax and not the actual DOM element so you can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass in the context of the element inside your ajax call. Another thing is that `live` has been deprecated you can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for delegated event handlers.

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n6GsZ/)

```
   $(this).find(".caption").find("#yes").on('click', function() {
             $.ajax({
                    url: 'prob.php',
                    data: {action: 'yes'},
                    type: 'post',
                    success:$.proxy( function (response) {
                            $(this).find(".caption").find("#change").text("Come on!");
                        },this),
                    error:$.proxy(function()
                    {
                       //
                    }, this)
                })
 });
```